# Instantiate Generic Type with params

Tags: java, generics

I have several types "Point". there is general class Point and several inheritants of it:
NEPoint extends Point

I have a generic Reader that reads points from some kind of Reader.

```
public class PointReader<T extends Point> extends BufferedReader {

   //there constructor


   public T readPoint() {
     T result = null;
     String str=readLine();
     //here I need to instantiate a type T with string parameter str in its constructor
    ...
   }
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: I found that one way to instantiate is using default constructor. Is there a way to instantiate with constructor that have parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241513/how-to-create-instance-of-a-class-with-the-parameters-in-the-constructor-using-r